# How to add link a table to a row

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database-design

I'm developing a Ruby on Rails application with MySQL and i have a Categories table in my Database.
I want to add sub categories to one of the categories.
i thought of creating a new table for sub categories or just add them to the same Categories table. can anyone help?

Comment: Why not just add a `parent_id` column?

Comment: You can add to `Categories` table `parent_category_id` field. In this field you will save id of parent category, if this field is null then category is on top level otherwise it's subcategory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `sub_category` is nothing but a `category` with a parent association, you could just store both `categories` and `sub_categories` in one table and wire up the association. This type of association is referred as self join association.

Try the following:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sub_categories, class_name: 'Category', foreign_key: :parent_id
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Category'
end
```

Refer to [Self Joins Association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins) for more info.

You need to setup the following migration:

```
class AddParentIdToCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column(:categories, :parent_id, :integer)
  end
end
```

And run the migration:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

If you are expecting your tree structure to be more complex, for example, sub_categories having sub_sub_categories and more, then you could take a look at several gems that abstract this feature.

Refer to [acts_as_tree](https://github.com/amerine/acts_as_tree), and [ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) fore more info,

Comment: Ok that was helpful, but now i still can't access them using `Category.sub_categories` . there should be some kind of referencing i should do using a migration but i'm not sure how to do it.
I normally use Mongodb with rails which is clearly more easy

Comment: What exactly you are trying to retrieve? Sub_categories are tied to a category instance, so you first need to load a category and then call sub_categories on it. If you what all sub_categories, then you need to define a named scope called sub_categories on Category where parent_id is nil.

Comment: I'm trying to retrieve sub_categories that are tied to a category.
i tried loading the instance but it keeps showing `undefined method `sub_categories' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Category:0x9b7e2ac>`

Comment: I already had the model and the migration for the category created before adding this relationship. I'm sure now after adding it i need to run a migration but i'm not sure how it should be made, so that's what i'm asking.

Comment: Added information about migration to the answer. But based on your error, it looks like it is not a migration issue. It must be due to the association not being set properly. Include the code for `Category` model for review.

Comment: Category model:

`class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
 default_scope { order(created_at: :desc) }
 has_many :articles, :dependent=>:destroy
 has_many :sub_categories, class_name: 'Category', foreign_key: :parent_id
   belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Category'
end`

Comment: Your model code seems to be fine. How are you loading the `Category` instance? Include the code where you load the instance, as well as full stacktrace for review.

Comment: okay i have a Category with id=2 that has 4 sub_categories.
when i call it with `Category.where(:id=>2).sub_categories`
i get this : 

 "undefined method `sub_categories` for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Category:0x9ddf118>
 from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:121:in method_missing
 from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:68:in method_missing.......".

but when i call it with `Category.all[6].sub_categories` there is no error and i can retrieve them.

Comment: When you use Category.where(id: 2), you get a collection not an instance. You need to use Category.find(2). If you need to use Category.where(id: 2), you need to call Category.where(id: 2).first to get an instance.